# How can I listen to multiple paths with Firebase AngularFire

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have an Administrator in a web app who can view records for one or more locations by simply selecting them from a list. How would I go about listening to event changes for all those locations so I could display updates on a single page ?

Should I have multiple $firebaseArrays, with each one pointing to a specific path? Is there any performance considerations with this ?

Answer (score 2):

A potential answer on [this thread](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/595):

> The main performance bottleneck you will see if on how much bandwidth
>   you send across the wire, not how many Firebase listeners you have set
>   up. If the data you sync to with $firebaseObject or $firebaseArray
>   rarely changes, then they will have hardly any performance impact. If
>   the data is constantly changing but you don't really care about those
>   changes, then you will be having a negative impact on performance.

I have not noticed a performance lag when using dozens of $firebaseArrays, but the changes are small on those refs as well.